# I have add data from google sheets to table,now i am trying to get value from button and get it to separate selected list

Tags: html, button, row, addition

```
<div style ="text-align:center;"><input style ="text-align:center;" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name"></div>

<table id = "myTable" align = center border = "1" cellspacing = "0" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th colSpan = 4 >ADDRESS</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<div>
<tbody id ="myTablebody" >
</tbody>
</div>
</table>

<script>  

document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input",searchdata);


function searchdata(){
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
console.log(filter);
if(filter.length > 3){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generatetable).getTableData(filter);
} else { 
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(removeChild).getTableData(filter);

}
}





function generatetable(dataArray){
var tbody = document.getElementById('myTablebody')

var node= document.getElementById("myTablebody");
node.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(n => n.remove());


dataArray.forEach(function(r){
var row0 = document.createElement("tr");
var col1 = document.createElement("td");
col1.textContent = r[0];
var col2 = document.createElement("td");
col2.textContent = r[1];
var col3 = document.createElement("td");
col3.textContent = r[2];
var col4 = document.createElement("td");
col4.textContent = r[3];
var col5 = document.createElement("td");
col5.textContent = r[4];
var col6 = document.createElement("Button");
col6.textContent = r[5];



row0.appendChild(col1);
row0.appendChild(col2);
row0.appendChild(col3);
row0.appendChild(col4);
row0.appendChild(col5);
row0.appendChild(col6);




tbody.appendChild(row0); 



});
}


function removeChild(){
var node= document.getElementById("myTablebody");
node.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(n => n.remove());
};
```

This is how I created the table-body script

```
function getTableData(filter){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var trn = ss.getSheetByName("DATA BASE");
var originaldata = trn.getRange(1,1,trn.getLastRow(),6).getValues();
var salesRep = filter;
var data = originaldata.filter(function(item){return item[0].indexOf(salesRep) > -1;});
return data;
}
```

I have add data from google sheets to table body, search and filter to table body i have added button dynamically now i am trying to get value of selected row from button and get it to separate selected list. pls suggest in pure java-script would be much appreciated...